# "Keep one's fingers crossed" VS Wish

Tags: meaning, idioms

I am wondering how the following sentences differ in meaning:

> I wish you success. 
> I [keep my fingers crossed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep-your-fingers-crossed) for you.

I cannot come up with any nuance myself.

Comment: I think there should be a 'will' in the second sentence - 'I keep...' sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wishing someone success is a simple expression of goodwill.

Keeping your fingers crossed is a superstitious gesture which is supposed to bring good luck. Doing it for someone else (or claiming to) implies 'hoping for the best', perhaps fearing that what they plan to do is something risky.